# How do I test this method in this class to see if it's working but it has no main in it

Tags: java, testing, junit

So this is link below the class and it has no main method and I am trying to test and see if every line in the methods[[1]:][1] is processing and if not where is it getting errors.

Comment: ode is too long and I am trying to figure to provide a link but it seems it not working and I am unable to post because its too long

Comment: If there is a specific method that you want to test, it shouldn't be too long to post. If it is, you need to break it up into smaller pieces of functionality.

Comment: [Post your relevent code here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44442/181088), rather than linking.

Comment: You can't link the code from your e-mail account. You _could_ use a site like [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to store it and show us, but the preffered way is to copy the __relevant parts of it__ here. We don't like linking the code, because it can disappear after some time and the question would not be valid for the future.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/), or, more specifically, the site under ["Getting Started"](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) there.

For short, if you had a class `Dog` with a method like this

```
public boolean isBrown() {
    // some hard & heavy logic
}
```

you'd probably like to see whether it works or not. To do that, you'd create a `test` package within your application with some testing classes, one of them could should be named `DogTests` and contain this:

```
public class DogTests {
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void nullDogShouldFailWithNpe() throws Exception {
        new Dog(3, 14, null);
    }

    @Test
    public void brownDogShouldBeBrown() throws Exception {
        Animal animal  = new Dog(3, 14, "brown");
        assertTrue(animal.isBrown());
    }

    @Test
    public void greenDogShouldNotBeBrown() throws Exception {
        Animal animal  = new Dog(3, 14, "green");
        assertTrue(animal.isBrown());
    }
}
```

You can find documentation on those `assert` methods [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html).

Can you see the `@Test` annotation above the method? That is a JUnit 4 construct that says *"Hey, I'm a test method. When running tests from this class, run me, too!"* There's no need for `main()` method here - when you'll try to "run" the containing class, your IDE will notice *all* the `@Test` annotated methods itself, run them, and show you the test results.

You can even arrange multiple test suites, run the tests concurrently, run them automatically on building the application and all other sorts of testing magic... Start with this, dig on the website and you'll soon discover more of the unit testing goodness.

Answer (score 0):

When the methods being tested are non-static, you first construct the object and then you can call the methods.  If your JUnit test case is in a package of the same name as the class being tested, you can access both public and protected members.  Here's an example test against the `HashMap` class which has no main method.

```
public void testDuplicateKey() throws Exception {
  HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap();
  // setup
  map.put("key1", "value1");
  map.put("key2", "value2");
  map.put("key3", "value3");
  assertEquals(3, map.size());
  // overwrite an existing key
  map.put("key2", "value4");
  assertEquals(3, map.size());
  assertEquals("value4", map.get("key2"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use BlueJ. It lets you work with objects without any Main methods present.

Simply import the Java file(s) to the IDE and right-click on the Class Diagram presentation of the class you get, to make objects of it. The IDE is very basic and user-friendly in that it works a lot in picture representations of classes and objects.

When you have an object of the specified class or classes, you get objects at the bottom of the IDE which you can right-click on to interact with. Good luck.

Comment: Some people seriously don't know when to downvote. You should only downvote when the answer is not valid. My answer is perfectly valid ._.

Comment: It may be, but you didn't say _why_ it is valid. I really don't find your answer useful in any way. Which Java IDE _doesn't_ let you work with classes without `main()`? In what way is BlueJ better in this, how could OP use the functionality you are reffering to? I don't know it. I would like to know it, but you didn't specify any details and I probably won't try to read the whole BlueJ documentation to find out. Point a finger at the right feature / page / documentation and you may earn your upvote.